# Qiskit - How to get statevector for each shot?

Tags: qiskit, measurement

I have a simple circuit which I run for 10 shots:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

from qiskit import Aer, execute, QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

backend = Aer.get_backend("statevector_simulator")
qc2 = QuantumCircuit(2, 1)
qc2.h(0)
qc2.measure([0], [0])
print(qc2)
result = execute(qc2, backend=backend, shots=10).result()
```

[image]

Now, when I print the state vector with:

```
print('State after measurement:', result.get_statevector())
```

The output is:

> State after measurement: Statevector([1.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j],
> dims=(2, 2))

The question is that to which of the 10 shots does this state vector belong to? Depending on the measurement, the state vector should be different - when q0 is measured as 0 and when q0 is 1.

And how do I get the statevector for each shot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`save_statevector`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.library.save_statevector.html) simulator instruction.

To save the statevector for each shot, set `pershot` value to `True`:

```
from qiskit import Aer, execute, QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.providers.aer.library import save_statevector

backend = Aer.get_backend("statevector_simulator")
qc2 = QuantumCircuit(2, 1)
qc2.h(0)
qc2.measure([0], [0])

qc2.save_statevector(label = 'test', pershot = True)
result = execute(qc2, backend = backend, shots = 10).result()

print(result.data(0)['test'])
```

Answer (score 2):

To your first question, you see the `statevector` of the last shot performed. The [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/27090/20825) by Egretta Thula will get you the `statevecor` for each shot. Just to make sure we are on the same page, it is crucial if you save your `statevector` before or after the measurement. After the measurement the superposition collapses and your staevector is either $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$.

If you place `save_statevecor()` before the measurement, it will be the same for each shot, since H-Gate brings your system into state $\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$.

You can also get the readouts for each shot with `get_memory()` method of the `result`. For that, you need to set the option `memory=True`.

```
result = backend.run(qc2, shots=10, memory=True).result()
memory = result.get_memory(qc2)
print(memory)
```